# using tcpdump how to capture only traffic between my server and elastic search database

Tags: tcpdump

I want to use tcpdump to capture traffic between my server and the elastic search database also I would like to capture traffic of one specific url POST https://vpc-my-es-3-abcd.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/idx_abc_prod/doc/_search

Comment: `tcpdump` works on OSI level 4, not above. It doesn't know what "URL" or "HTTP request" is, at best it knows IP addresses, IP transport protocols and ports. What problem exactly you attempt to solve and why you chose such hardcore way to approach it? What other ways you considered?

Comment: Also traffic will be encrypted if you use https so you dont able to see http headers for example